# rabbitmq - how to handle a case where unacked messages are lost

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

Suppose I prefetch 10 messages from RabbitMQ, and before I get a chance to acknowledge them, they are deleted from my local array for whatever reason. In that case, the broker will not be able to send me any new messages, since the previous ones were not acknowledged. How do I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: From what I remember from RabbitMQ (which also seems to be stated [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)), RabbitMQ will only start redelivering those messages if the client exits (or rather, when its channel/connection gets closed).

Comment: @robertklep Are you saying that if I restart my consumer the messages that I lost will be redelivered?

Comment: Yes, provided that you didn't turn off message acknowledgement, any messages that get sent to a client and weren't acknowledged by that client when the client connection dies, will be redelivered.